# Traffic on my homepage is redirected to another site

Tags: security

I think my website has been hacked.

Some users reported redirects from my home page to another website.

The problem only concerns the home page and not the other pages.

Also, when I type [www.domain.com/index.php](http://www.domain.com/index.php) there is no problem. But when I type "www.domain.com" I find myself on another website.

My site has been hard-coded with an obsolete PHP version (5.3) and hosted by OVH on a shared server.

Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Comment: Please look at https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Do you run on Apache? Check your `.htaccess` for hardcoded redirects if no file is specified.

Comment: @Martin Yes I run on Apache and .htaccess is OK

Comment: @Panganino then for a possible immediate fix you can check your `.htaccess` file is working correctly. If your system has been compromised this won't fix it but can hlep your website to work as intended.

Comment: @Martin .htaccess works fine. Currently my website works as intended, the problem occurs for a while during the day.